# curl https://cpanmin.us fails on CentOS 7

Tags: curl, centos7

```
$ docker run centos:7.1.1503 curl  https://cpanmin.us
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

I know we can use the direct URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/master/cpanm which works fine.

What I want to know is that what is the cause of this error and how to solve it.

Below is the output of -vvv option.

```
$ docker run centos:7.1.1503 curl -vvvv  https://cpanmin.us
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to cpanmin.us port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 104.28.29.17...
* Connected to cpanmin.us (104.28.29.17) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12286 (SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP)
* Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
* Error in TLS handshake, trying SSLv3...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: cpanmin.us
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://cpanmin.us'
* About to connect() to cpanmin.us port 443 (#1)
*   Trying 104.28.29.17...
* Connected to cpanmin.us (104.28.29.17) port 443 (#1)
* TLS disabled due to previous handshake failure
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12286 (SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP)
* Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
* Closing connection 1
curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine with my curl version (not using CentOS 7), so a guess here is that the version you're using is built with a TLS library that doesn't have a new enough set of ciphers supported that the site seems to require.

Comment: do you know how to update it? "yum update" makes nothing because it's already latest version of CentOS7.

Comment: I added the output of -vvv option.